# Lost power to ceiling lights after taking down light fixture

Tags: receptacle, light-fixture

I was trying to replace a light fixture in my old Chicago apartment yesterday and quickly realized I was out of my depth trying to identify wires etc. I capped the wires and flipped the breaker back on, and when I did, most of the ceiling lights in the apartment and two of the outlets didn’t come back on. We’ve flipped the breaker off and on again to make sure it’s not stuck, and pushed reset buttons for outlets that have them, but nothing has worked. How badly have I screwed up here?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhdVN.jpg

Comment: If you are seeking help restoring power a good place to start would be a photo of the wires in the ceiling j-box. Since you are in Chicago it is likely you have conduit, using conduit there are so many possible wire color combinations successful guessing of connections would be hard.

Comment: It sounds like you broke the circuit.  Was there more than one pair(a black and a white or different colour pairs) and you capped each off separately?  Imagine all you have to do is connect blacks to blacks, and whites to whites, but post pictures first.

Comment: Edited to add a photo of the current situation, as well as the wiring when I first took down the old fixture. I tried not to meddle too much with the original arrangement, but there was one wire (the red one painted over with white, with a red cap) that I just couldn’t figure out where it came from, so I feel like it could be causing some of my problems?

Comment: Do you remember which wires were the ones connected to the old fixture, and that you capped off, versus which ones were already wire-nutted together?  You didn't add ALL the nuts shown, right?  Which ones did you add?   My guess is that the two loose reds lower right were BOTH connected to the light, and you just need to connect them back to each other.  And that the bundle of whites was connected to the light via a pigtail that you removed.  Close?

Comment: Heres how it looked when I took the fixture down: https://m.imgur.com/a/tjxIycw the reds were not connected by the time I got the picture, but I wonder if maybe they were before and one of them slipped out when I started removing the light? Should I try connecting the reds or is that too risky?

Comment: No don’t just connect blacks to blacks and whites to whites if there is a switch leg (almost certain to be there) that will create a dead short. 
We would need a picture of the wires at the switch. The blacks could be hots, the reds switched hots and the whites neutrals. 
If the switch has a black and white it is a standard switch leg. In conduit it is common for pro’s to use black for hot and red for switched hot. If black and white are used to the switch white is the hot and black is the switched hot!  You really need to check the switch wiring prior to trying anything.

Answer (score 2):

Safety ground is plainly identified as a bare or green or yellow/green wire.  Other than ground... there were exactly two wires going to the lamp.  The new lamp attaches to those same two.

It is that simple.

Thus there are no more than 2 wire nuts you would possibly have any reason to disassemble.  Sometimes we get people whose curiosity has gotten the best of them, and disassemble *more than they need to*. In that case, it can usually only be reassembled with skill, tools and iteratively interacting with the wires in question - you need a professional who has the qualifications.  Blind, ignorant experimentation is BAD. There are many combinations that will work *and then kill you*.

How do electricians pass on knowledge about circuits? *By how it is already wired*.  There's no other storage for the information, and wire color is not meaningful enough to be helpful.

If each lamp wire spliced to 1 wire from the ceiling, life would be simple.  You would never have cause to disturb any other wires.

The bad news is, often one of the lamp wires attaches to 2 or more wires from the ceiling.  The good news is, these are *usually* all neutral wires.  If a wire is neutral, it must be white. (The white goop put on most wires by the drywallers/painters must be disregarded.  That is not an electrical marking. Colored wires are never allowed to be re-marked white to be neutral... and now, I think I see why LOL).

However, white wires can be re-marked to be a hot, and 90% of the time when this is done, the marking isn't actually done, it's a shibboleth between electricians to know "oh yeah, that's a hot".

Since the lamp's "hot" wire is only energized when the light is desired to be on, it is usually only a single wire.  (unless several lamps are controlled by the same switch).

However in your case I see multiple non-white wires that appear to have been disturbed. The best we can hope for is that

- this is actually a *fan rated* box and they brought two hot wires up there, one for the fan, one for the light.  In which case connect the lamp's hot wire to one or the other, and see which one works.
- Or there are 2 lights controlled by this switch, in which case those wires go together with the lamp light. Then I would expect 2 wires from the wall to go to the lamp's hot.

Comment: *white wires can be re-marked to be a hot* But I thought that was only for cables, *not* in conduit.